# How can I squash commits in git?

Tags: git

I want to simply squash a bunch of git commits that are no longer needed. I attempted to follow documentation from [this site](https://facwiki.cs.byu.edu/cs345/index.php/Git_basics#Flattening_Revision_History), but I ended up with git saying there is nothing to squash. I only have one branch, so I followed that section. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I were doing it I'd use "rebase". Assuming you have your branch checked out, and that it is branched from master, do

```
git rebase -i master
```

This will allow you to modify the commits from master to your current branch. In your case,  replace `pick` with `s` (for `squash`) or `f` (for `fixup`, which is a squash that drops the commit message of the squashed commit). Save and exit (ZZ in Vim), and rebase will do its magic. Rebase is a more general solution as in the same operation you can remove, re-order, and reword commits.

The rebase settings will open in Vim, or whichever editor you set in the `EDITOR` environment variable. In Vim, navigate to start of the line with the commit you wish to squash (with arrow keys or mouse), `cw` to delete `pick` and enter insert mode, `f` for fixup or `s` for squash, then `ZZ` to save and exit.

---

As a side note, the link you gave suggests flatting your feature branch into a single commit. In my opinion this is an awful idea. Commits should represent a meaningful set of changes. A branch is the set of these changes that represents a feature. Squashing everything into one huge commit means it will be harder for other developers to follow your changes.

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try.  I am actually not using it for software development at all, but to track configuration files and other stuff in Linux.  I want a backup that only goes back so far, so in essence,  want to remove history greater than 30 days.  That is why I thought squashing it would be ideal as well as remove unnecessary space taken up by the revisions.

Comment: Ok, I think it worked this time, when I did -i, I was prompted to edit the commit messages and the rebase actually appeared to take place.  When I didn't do the -i earlier, none of the commits were actually squashed.

Comment: @Walter if you do need to compress git at all, I think git gc does that, which git does of its own accord anyway.

Comment: @Walter, squashing commits doesn't take up less space (or the space saved is negligible). Git may not be the right tool for what you want to do.

Comment: Yeah, it isn't designed for that, but I like it better than other available tools.